# Relation between expectations of two random variables

Tags: expected-value, probability-inequalities

I have two random variable X and Y. I know that
$$E_X\left[X \log \frac{X}{e}\right] < E_Y\left[Y \log \frac{Y}{e}\right]$$

Using the above relation can I say anything about the relation between $E_X[X]$ and $E_Y[Y]$ ?

Comment: Is that all you know about these random variables?

Comment: If needed, we can assume that the random variables X and Y are independent.

Comment: Since you only ask about marginal expectations, independence is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I will only give some hints.

Clearly, $X>0$ is a positive random variable for this to make sense. Note that $x \log(x/e) = x\log x - x\log e = x\log x -x$.  Define $f(x) = x\log x -x$.  So your claim becomes $\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}  \E_X f(X) < \E_Y f(Y)$.  Calculate the two first derivatives of $f$, and conclude that $f$ is convex.  Then: Jensen inequality:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality